# How to get User home in C (platform-independent manner)?

Tags: c

How to get User home in C (platform-independent manner)?

I can use `getenv("%HOME%")` on linux and similar string on windows.. but I need a **platform independent** manner?

Comment: `getenv("%HOME%")` does **not** work on Linux.

Comment: Yes, remove the `%` signs. They're bogus (not part of the variable name but part of DOS batchfile syntax).

Answer (score 4):

You could also use `getpwuid()` on *nix systems, if `$HOME` isn't set:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  struct passwd *passwdEnt = getpwuid(getuid());
  char *home = passwdEnt->pw_dir;
  printf("home: %s\n", home);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is a pretty nifty solution in itself :)

Answer (score 2):

This **is** platform dependent. Use #ifdef's to select the method compiletime.

```
#if defined(_WIN32)
// get HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH from environment
#elif defined(__linux__)
// get HOME from environment
#else
#error Platform not supported yet
#endif
```

Comment: `defined(__linux__)` is definitely wrong. Just use `#else`. And environment variables do not have `%` signs around them. That's some Windows batchfile nonsense..

Comment: @R: Removed the %'s. What's wrong with `defined` - how else would you do a series of checks for a series of platforms that all implement things differently? Nested `#ifdef`?

Comment: @R: `defined(__linux__)` is perfectly valid. This is called *defensive programming*, because the author already knows how to handle Windows and Linux, but (maybe) has never seen another platform. And in that case it is better to not compile the program at all. It's clearly better than having a program that runs everywhere but doesn't work as expected.

Comment: That's completely nonsensical. `getenv("HOME")` is correct on any POSIX system (and really ANY system but Windows where a "home directory" makes sense), and `__linux__` is completely nonstandard. At least `__linux__` is in the reserved namespace so it's valid, but back in the day plenty of software used utterly idiotic and nonconformant things like `defined(linux)` or `defined(unix)`. In any case there's no excuse for writing Linux-specific software. The amount of effort needed to make it portable to any reasonably-good POSIX system is minimal.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want. If you need to know for an authoritative reason or need to know a different user's home directory, use `getpwuid_r`. Otherwise, `getenv("HOME")` is the correct way.